# Netbeans formatting issue

Tags: netbeans, code-formatting

I am trying to set my formatting to the way my professor wants it for my class, and everything is right except that public and private have their own line and cannot find the option to get rid of that. Thanks for the help!! Id post a picture but i guess you cant do that after you first make an account.

Right now it looks like this after it is formatted:

```
public
    boolean add(T payload)
{
    abarr_ListNode<T> nextNode = new abarr_ListNode<T>(payload);
    abarr_ListNode<T> firstNode = getFirstNode();
    abarr_ListNode<T> lastNode = getLastNode();
```

Id like it to look like this:

```
public boolean add(T payload)
{
    abarr_ListNode<T> nextNode = new abarr_ListNode<T>(payload);
    abarr_ListNode<T> firstNode = getFirstNode();
    abarr_ListNode<T> lastNode = getLastNode();
```

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe instead of posting a picture, you could post a code snippet to demonstrate what the code looks like now, and how you would like it to look.

Answer (score 3):

For the modifier (public, private etc...) check the following:

> Tools --> Options --> Editor -->
>   Formatting.
>
> Select **Java** from the **Languages** drop
>   down list.
>
> Select **Alignment** from the **Category**
>   drop down list.

Ensure that the **after modifiers** checkbox is unchecked.

To place the curly-brace on a new line (from the same formatting tab):

> Select **Braces** from the Category drop
>   down list.
>
> Select **New Line** from whichever of
>   the drop down lists in the **Braces
>   Placement** Section is relevant to
>   you.